# How to find a high power of a given permutation?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Given the permutation $\pi = (4 2 5 3 1)$, I want to find $\pi^{25}$, specifically the value $\pi ^{25}(3)$.

How to approach this problem, without multiplying $\pi$ by itself more than twenty times?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't have to: a cycle of length $n$ has order $n$, hence $\pi^5=\operatorname{id}$, and *a fortiori*  $\pi^{25}=\operatorname{id}$, so  $\pi^{25}(3)=3$.

Comment: The compulsive & brave anonymous downvoter struck again!